is it possible to save the state of a cryptographically strong random number generator?
Background: Suppose, I want to use a Cryptographically strong random number generator for simulating random moves of a particle simulation using mote carlo method.
I want to run the simulation for, say, 100 million sweeps and save the state of the random number generator for two reasons:
(1) if the simulation run fails at some point, I can start it from the exact point where it failed rather than to restart it from the beginning.
(2) I want to save the state after the simulation is stabilized so that I can use the checkpoint to get "equilibrated" readings.
Question:
Can I save the state of a cryptographically strong random number generator for future use?

Yes, absolutely (just as with any pseudorandom number generator).
Just make sure you are using one that is deterministic (also known as a DRBG), e.g., AES-CTR, ChaCha20, NIST Hash_DRBG, NIST HMAC_DRBG, ANSI X9.17.
Avoid random number generators that also reseed periodically, such as Yarrow, Fortuna, Unix /dev/random, CryptGenRandom.
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

how about PCG32?

@user366312, Never heard of it.  I suggest learning the definition of a DRBG, studying PCG32, and trying to figure out whether it satisfies the definition.  If you're still unsure, ask a new question, and provide all relevant context, including what prevents you from answering that on your own.

Yes if you have a deterministic random number generator which is in some state S and which simultaneously calculates a random number and a deterministic new state.
In practice, the code implementing the random number generator may not be under your control and there may be no way to read or write the state from the outside. So the state can be read and later restored, but you can’t.
Cryptographically secure random number generators may just be clever with not much more state than a linear congruential PRNG, or they may have a lot of state (but non secure PRNG may have a lot of state as well).

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_numbers/PCG32 --- how about this one? Is this dependable for non-cryptographic operations?

Obviously what they call “state” and “sequence” in that article does together form the real state of the random number generator. To repeat your random numbers, you need to copy and restore the complete state - both the bits this article calls “state” and the bits this article calls “sequence”.
